# htaccess redirect not 100% working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to be able to redirect all pages:

`www.mywebsite.com/123/abc` (including `www.mywebsite.com/123/abc/`)

to

```
www.mywebsite.com/abc-newpage
```

with an optional closing slash.

(The 123 is effectively becoming redundant)

I know that technically a webpage with a closing slash is different from one without (in some cases).

Here is what I have so far:

```
RewriteRule ^123/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ $1-newpage [R=301]
```

It works for non-closing slash URLs but

```
www.mywebsite.com/123/abc/
```

goes to

```
www.mywebsite.com/abc/-newpage
```

Hope this makes sense.

Surely the statement limiting it to lower or upper case alpha or numbers `(([a-zA-Z0-9]+))` should exclude the slash?

Cheers
Da

Answer (score 0):

characters can be excluded in square brackets starting with '^'. Your RewriteRule seems to be correct though. I have copied your code to my .htaccess (www.paywithafacebookpost.com) and when typing e.g. www.paywithafacebookpost.com/123/abc/ you see the correct redirect. Do you have other rules in your .htaccess?